# Cumulative Occupied Space - Closed form solution to the integral from 0 to x of the "union" of multiple rectangular functions

Tags: calculus, integration

I have a function defined as the "union" of $N$ rectangular functions
$$h(r) = \max_{i=1,...,N} \mathrm{rect}(r, r_i^-, r_i^+)$$
where $\mathrm{rect}(r, r_i^-, r_i^+) = 1$ if $r^-_i \leq r \leq r^+_i$ and $0$ otherwise. Thus, $h(r)$ is $1$ in regions of the space where least one rectangular function is $1$, hence why I am calling this function the union of multiple rectangles.

I want to calculate the following integral
$$f(x) = \int_0^x h(r) dr$$
Thus calculating for any value $x$, the cumulative space occupied by the union of the multiple rectangles starting in 0.

I tried summing the integrals of each rectangular function, but in regions where two or more rectangles overlap, the integral grows with a slope greater than one. So I tried to subtract the integrals of the pairwise overlaps between rectangles, but that does not work in regions where three or more rectangles overlap because the overlapped region is subtracted too many times. So this route would take me into considering ever greater order interactions which is not very efficient.

I also tried to sort the different $r_i^-$ and $r_i^+$, then identifying which of these were between $x$ and $0$. I then calculated the distance between consecutive $r_i^{-/+}$ and summed it if the $h(r)$ function is $1$ in that interval.

Currently, I'm using an algorithm to find the limits of the rectangles which result from the "union" operation but it is not very efficient/elegant. It has cubic complexity and finds for every $r_i^-$ what is the greatest $r_j^+$ such that $h(r)$ function is always $1$ in that interval. Then, we get the limits of the connex rectangles which resulted from the union, thus, we can sum the integrals of each because we're sure they don't overlap.

Of course, all these approaches consider a lot of corner cases which results in convoluted and inneficient solutions. So I was wondering if anyone would have an idea on how to solve this more efficiently. Any help would be much appreciated, thank you.